# How do I run multiple Unix commands?

Tags: linux, command

So I have to run a cut and a sort file at once. I'm using this command:

`sort -k2 customers;cut -f7-31 customers`

The objective is to cut lines 7-31 then organize them in alphabetical order but I am not sure how to achieve it. Any input will help, thank you.

Comment: "cut lines 7-31" - lines or fields? or columns? `cut` can't cut lines, so I want to be sure what you're asking. Any chance of a minimal example?

Comment: here is literally the question:

Use vi to create a file called ‘my_customers’ with a proper prologue. This script should 
use ‘cut’ and ‘sort’ to create a listing of the ‘customers’ file containing the customer 
name and phone sorted by customer name. The ‘customers’ file has the following fixed 
length format: 
 
Field Position 
----------------------- ---------- 
Customer number 1-5 
Name 7-31 
City 33-47 
State 49-50 
Zip 54-59 
Phone 60-71

Comment: im able to cut the lines by using cut -f7-31 customers, and then im also able to sort the same file by the names by using sort -k2 customers (2 representing the second column)now i just need it to give me the cut information in alphabetical order..im really new to this so im trying to explain the best i can

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The objective is to cut lines 7-31 ...

You can use `sed`:

```
sort -k2 customers | sed '7,31!d'
```

This would pipe the output of `sort` to `sed` which would display lines 7 - 31 (both inclusive) from the `sort` output.

---

In order to select a character range, you need to supply the `-c` option to `cut` and not `-f` (which selects fields):

```
sort -k2 customers | cut -c7-31
```

which would select characters 7 - 31 in each line from the `sort` output.

---

In order to `sort` the final output, use another pipeline:

```
sort -k2 customers | cut -c7-31 | sort
```

Comment: I don't get it - since `cut` and `sort` do not affect each other in any way, why even bother with `sort -k2` if you'll just resort later? Isn't your code pretty much equivalent to `cut -c7-31 | sort`?

Comment: @Amadan The idea that the OP perhaps needed was how to use multiple pipelines.  I don't disagree with the point about redundant `sort` to begin with.  That said, it always helps to have some sample input/output in the question.

Answer (score 1):

The key thing here is to use pipes which are one of the singularly most powerful things in the shell. See [Unix Pipes](http://www.cse.ohio-state.edu/~mamrak/CIS762/pipes_lab_notes.html)

Pipes in unix are wonderful; powerful. Did I already mention this?

To answer your question; change the `;`  to a `|` and remove the filename

```
sort -k2 customers | cut -f7-31
```

will run sort on customers file and send the output of that to the input of cut; no temporary files.

Generally you'd do

```
sort -k2 customers | cut -f7-31 > customers.modified
```

You can have as many commands in the pipeline as you like; so to remove duplicates you'd to

```
sort -k2 customers | uniq | cut -f7-31 > customers.modified
```