# How do i change the output order in a linux command

Tags: linux, command

there are 4 lines in this file, in the order of Course Number, Course Name,Number of Credits ,Department Code (Example CO117:Java Programming:3:CO) A and i have been instructed to cut fields 2 and 4, and then display it so field 4 is in alphabetical order and have it display so that field 4 is first followed by field 2. (Example CO Java Programming) but i can not seem to find out how. closest i can get is by using the command

"sort -k4 courses | cut -f2,4 -d:"

any help is appreciated

Comment: didn't I just read this question?  with a slightly different description...but the same question?

Comment: some what yes, but this one is asking to rearrange the output so field 4 is first and field 2 is second and i cant find a place in my book that helps

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I run multiple Unix commands?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19487836/how-do-i-run-multiple-unix-commands)

Comment: no that one was resolved, this is a little different like i said..i know how to sort and pipe into another command but what i DONT know is how to rearrange the output so that it reads the department code THEN the course name, catch my drift?

Comment: I've voted to close as it is a duplicate of your previous question but it is also not clear what you are asking and there is no real example data input and output.  You might like to read this if you need to ask for help on the Internet http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Comment: You could just say `sort -k4 courses | cut -d: -f4,2`

Comment: devnull that is close but wont work because it is still not flipped so that field 4 is displayed first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use `cut` to change the order of the fields.  Instead of `cut`, use:

```
awk -F: '{print $4, $2}' OFS=:
```

Comment: Oh my lord your awesome, although i had to add the awk -F: '{print $4, $2}' OFS=: courses | sort -k1 after it it works! thank you millions!!